# "not contains" query in SailsJS Waterline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

How can I create the `not contains` query that returns true if the item does not contain a certain value. I'm running mongoDB if it is relevant.

I can use the `contains` successfully however receive an error when I introduce the `not`. I've tried it with `find` and `where` but get the same regex error both times. I can add the exact error if its relevant.

Working version:

```
model.find({attribute: {'contains': value}})
  .exec(function(err, users) {
    // happy code
});
```

The following complains about some regex error:

```
model.find({attribute: {not: {'contains': value}}})
  .exec(function(err, users) {
    // sad code
});
```

There was an issue raised and closed in 2013 about this. Maybe something changed recently?
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/22

Comment: Did you try without quote ? {not : {contains : value}}

Comment: I'll be honest, I've tried adding quotes to `not` and also tried `Not` however I never thought to modify `contains` since it worked by itself. I'll give it a shot in the morning

Answer (score 1):

Alexei, I don't think this is supported by waterline currently. There is a related issue which is marked as feature and that you can track:
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/666

Comment: This is a devil Issue!

Answer (score 1):

So far, you can only use native feature of Mongodb I think.

```
 Model.native(function(err, collection) {
     collection.find({
        "attribute" : {
            $ne : value, //Not Equal
            //OR
            $nin : [value1, value2]// Not In
        }
     }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
         if (err) return callback(err, docs);

         res.json(null, docs);
     });
 });
```

Comment: Will try this in a few days